# java.lang. RuntimeException No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3)

Tags: java, android, retrofit, otto

I'm trying to update this [RetroFit + Otto tutorial](https://medium.com/@ZkHaider/retrofit-otto-networking-made-easy-on-android-d268025235e1), so my code updated is:

**IWeather.java**

RetroFit 2.+ doesn't allow to return `void`, so instead of `void getWeather(...)` I added `Call<Weather> getWeather(...)`.

```
public interface IWeather {

    @GET("/{latitude},{longitude}")
    Call<Weather> getWeather(@Path("latitude") String latitude,
                             @Path("longitude") String longitude,
                             Callback<Weather> callback);
}
```

**ForecastClient.java**

RetroFit 2.+ has changed his constructor, so the new `ForecastClient` has the next form. The `IllegalArgumentException` points to the `weather.getWeather(...)` method.

```
public class ForecastClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
    private static final String API_KEY = "******************";
    public static final String API_URL = BASE_URL + API_KEY + "/";

    private static ForecastClient mForecastClient;
    private static Retrofit mRetroAdapter;

    public static ForecastClient getClient() {
        if (mForecastClient == null) {
            mForecastClient = new ForecastClient();
        }
        return mForecastClient;
    }

    private ForecastClient() {
        mRetroAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .build();
    }

    public void getWeather(String latitude, String longitude, Callback<Weather> callback) {
        IWeather weather = mRetroAdapter.create(IWeather.class);
        weather.getWeather(latitude, longitude, callback);
    }
}
```

**ForecastManager.java**

```
public class ForecastManager {

    private Context mContext;
    private Bus mBus;
    private ForecastClient sForecastClient;

    public ForecastManager(Context context, Bus bus) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mBus = bus;
        sForecastClient = ForecastClient.getClient();
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onGetWeatherEvent(GetWeatherEvent getWeatherEvent) {
        String latitude = Double.toString(getWeatherEvent.getLatitude()).trim();
        String longitude = Double.toString(getWeatherEvent.getLongitude()).trim();

        Callback<Weather> callback = new Callback<Weather>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Weather> call, Response<Weather> response) {
                Log.d(ForecastManager.class.getSimpleName(), response.body().toString());
                mBus.post(new SendWeatherEvent(response.body()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Weather> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(ForecastManager.class.getSimpleName(), t.getMessage());
            }
        };

        sForecastClient.getWeather(latitude, longitude, callback);
    }
}
```

I'm receiving a No Retrofit annotation found and I guess the reason is something related with my callback, but it is a RetroFit callback, so I don't understand why the error.

The stacktrace points to the MainActivity, in particular to the Otto's method `post()` with a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not dispatch event`, caused by the error previously mentioned `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3)`:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.activity_main_textView)
    TextView textView;
    @BindView(R.id.activity_main_button)
    Button button;

    private static final double LATITUDE = **.******;
    private static final double LONGITUDE = **.******;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.activity_main_button)
    public void onClick(View view) {
        BusProvider.getInstace().post(new GetWeatherEvent(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE));
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onSendWeatherEvent(SendWeatherEvent sendWeatherEvent) {
        Weather weather = sendWeatherEvent.getWeather();
        Currently currently = weather.getCurrently();
        textView.setText(currently.getSummary());
    }
```

Any clue about where is the error or how should I handle the bus subscriptions, the callback, etcetera?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3)
```

As the error says, the problem is that the third parameter of the `getWeather` method does not have an annotation. The `Callback` class is used for the `Call#enqueue(Callback)` method.

Simply change

```
sForecastClient.getWeather(latitude, longitude, callback)
```

to

```
sForecastClient.getWeather(latitude, longitude).enqueue(callback)
```

and remove the third parameter.

Comment: It works like a charm. I'm pretty new using Otto and RetroFit and all the tutorials use old versions of this libraries.

Comment: Most of square's libraries have pretty good examples on their project pages, you should refer to them before tutorials when using libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Try it and modify your retrofit version number to `2.6.0`. The use of coroutines in `Retrofit 2.6.0` can return a `Response` object directly. If `await()` is not needed, Retrofit will automatically call it. This is not applicable when the version is below `2.6.0`.